# Unlockables/bonus levels in Bit Trip Runner?

Tags: bit-trip-runner

I just beat Bit Trip Runner and...well...I was a little bit disappointed by the ending on Normal mode. Are there any bonus levels or unlockables I can obtain by meeting special criteria, such as beating it on a higher difficulty or getting all the gold across both the normal and bonus stages, or is that really the end of the game?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bit.Trip Complete! will soon be out for the Wii. It features all 6 games in the bit.trip franchise, and [20 bonus levels for each game within the collection as well](http://www.nintendolife.com/news/2011/09/feature_bittrip_saga_vs_bittrip_complete).

So, not sure if you want to shell out for a whole new game (but it's an awesome Indie dev, so maybe you do?), but the challenges are supposedly FIENDISHLY DIFFICULT. Given that each chapter of Runner has less than 20 levels, you're getting more than a full third of extra Bit.trip running goodness!

Comment: Wow. Surprise surprise. So I guess there are no bonus levels in the game standard?

Comment: @Mana - alas, no. But if you haven't gotten perfect on all the retro warpzones, it sounds like you might have more to do yet. :)